# How can I run a streamlit application?

Tags: python, web-applications, streamlit

my streamlit has been successfully installed but it doesn't want to run the streamlit app, what can I do?

I tried updating my python, as well as my streamlit but I have no successes. I even tried working on a virtual environment.

Comment: Definitely not enough info to help. What's your OS? How you run app? What errors occur? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)